# Semantic analysis of text

Tags: nlp, keyword, semantic-web

Which tools would you recommend to look into for semantic analysis of text?

Here is my problem: I have a corpus of words (keywords, tags).

I need to process sentences, input by users and find if they are semantically close to words in the corpus that I have.

Any kind of suggestions (books or actual toolkits / APIs) are very welcome.

Regards,

Comment: Related question: Algorithms for creating relations between two words  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867888/creating-algorithms-for-creating-relations-between-two-words/4878459#4878459

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some useful links to begin with:**

- http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/sentiment/read-me.html
- http://kmandcomputing.blogspot.com/2008/06/opinion-mining-with-rapidminer-quick.html
- http://rapid-i.com/content/blogcategory/38/69/
- http://www.cs.cornell.edu/People/pabo/movie-review-data/otherexperiments.html
- http://wordnet.princeton.edu/

**Tools/Libraries:**

- Open NLP
- lingpipe

Answer (score 2):

If you consider your corpus as an ontology, Apache Stanbol - http://incubator.apache.org/stanbol/ - might be useful. It uses dbpedia as the default ontology while analyzing text. Although it is incubating, enhancer component is good enough foe adoption. So, you can give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can try some WordNet similarity measurements. Ted Pedersen has a compilation of those metrics in [WordNet::Similarity](http://wn-similarity.sourceforge.net/) which you can experiment and look into. There are counterpart implementations in other languages (e.g. Java).